# Centralizer Proof: $A \subseteq C(C(A))$

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing

Show that $ A \subseteq C(C(A))$

Let $G$ be a group and $ A \subseteq G $. The centralizer of a subset of A is the set $C(A)=\{x\in G : ax=xa$ for all $a \in A\}$.

*Isn't this obvious because $A=A$ so $A\subseteq A$ and $A \subseteq C(A)$ so $A$ must be in $C(C(A))$?

Any suggestions or hints would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Elements of $C(A)$ are group elements. $A$ is a subset of $G$, so $A \notin C(A)$ as $A$ is not a group element.

Comment: What do you mean by $A\in C(A)$? $A$ is a subset of $G$ so it can not be an element of $C(A)$. This a typical homework for a beginner in group theory.

Comment: Consider a nonabelian group $G$ and $A=G$ to see that $A\not\subseteq C(A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jack indicated, $A \subseteq C_G(A)$ if and only if $A$ is abelian. So want you want to prove is almost obvious. Let $a \in A$ and pick an arbitrary $x \in C_G(A)$. By the definition of the centralizer $ax=xa$, and hence $a \in C_G(C_G(A))$, that is $A \subseteq C_G(C_G(A))$. And this inclusion can be strict: can you find a (non-abelian) subgroup $A$ of $G= Q \times Q$ ($Q$ the quaternion group of order 8), such that $A \subsetneq C_G(C_G(A))$?